# How to remove angular growl notification from controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, growl

I'm adding a notification to may page when I make a server call and I want to remove it when the call is successful. Can you please guide me how to update/remove that same notification?

https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl

Comment: There is no native functionality that I can find that would support programmatically removing messages. You can time them, wait for the user to close them, or extend the library to support removing them. It's a fairly simple library, so extending it to support what you want shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 2):

The **warn**/**info**/**error** methods of angular growl return a reference to the message. You can call the `destroy()` method on the message to close it programmatically